# AWS DynamoDB Transaction issues on PUT (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to update 2 tables transactionally. The first table is called customer, second is called customer_detail.

for the first table, I create a new row if it doesnt exist. if it does exist I can ignore the whole process. If the record does not exist, add data to tables. Can someone help?

```
dynamodb.transact_write_items(
                TransactItems=[
                    {
                        'Update': {
                            'TableName': 'customer',
                            'Key': {
                                "id": {"S": unique_key},
                                "name": {"S": payload['value']}
                            },
                            'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                                '#vl': "name"
                            },
                            'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
                                ':val': {'S': payload['value']}
                            },
                            'UpdateExpression': "SET #vl = :val"

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Put": {
                            "Item": {
                                "id": {"S": unique_key},
                                "value": {"S": payload['value']}
                            },
                            "TableName": 'customer_detail',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            )
```

Error from this code is

```
botocore.errorfactory.TransactionCanceledException: An error occurred (TransactionCanceledException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [ValidationError, None]
```

Comment: What is the result of this? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana I have updated the question with errors received